# Should I normalize this (users) table?

Tags: mysql, database, database-normalization

This is for users data in job portal.

Wright now I've this cols in one `users` table:

```
user_id
email
password
registred_date
online (user online ? 1 : 0)
last_visit
activation (activation hash for not activated users, 1 for activated)
firstname
lastname
nickname
age
location
range (from location)
telephone
skype
qualifications (IDs from qualifications table, ie: "1,4,5,21,46,52")
education
desired_salary
desired_hourly_rate
hourly_rate_fixed (hourly_rate can be fixed ? 1 : 0)
user_image
```

Basically all cols except `password, activation, user_id` are intended to be displayed.

Do you think this table should be normalized?

What i was thinking about is to split it into 2 tables.

One form account identyfication / authorization / system:

```
user_id
email
password
registred_date
online (user online ? 1 : 0)
last_visit
activation (activation hash for not activated users, 1 for activated)
```

Second for user personal / profile data:

```
user_id
firstname
lastname
nickname
age
location
range (from location)
telephone
skype
qualifications (IDs from qualifications table, ie: "1,4,5,21,46,52")
education
desired_salary
desired_hourly_rate
hourly_rate_fixed (hourly_rate can be fixed ? 1 : 0)
user_image
```

Answer (score 1):

If you should normalize it is your call.
Here are some facts:
1.A normalized database/tables needs less space, but since space is so cheap it doesn't matter. btw its just nicer if you normalize your db and your not looking like a noob.
2.Searching in a normalized database is slower because you will have to make joins etc.

so in the end it's your call but i would normalize it.